# Reading through null pointer in #define with condition

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I have definition of macro `printerr`

```
#define CLR_R "\x1b[1;31m" 
#define CLR_N "\x1b[0m"
#define printerr(caller,msg) (caller==NULL)?printf(CLR_R "%s" CLR_N "\n",msg) \
   : printf(CLR_R "%s:" CLR_N " %s\n",caller,msg)
```

And get warning

> warning: reading through null pointer (argument 2), when calling `printerr(NULL,"error");`.

How to suppress this warning?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define printerr(caller,msg) (caller==NULL)?printf("%s\n",msg) : \
    printf("%s: %s\n",caller,msg)
void main() {
    printerr("Error","error occurred"); //will be ok
    printerr(NULL,"error"); //Warning: is caller even checked here?
}
```

Comment: what are `CLR_R` and `CLR_N`

Comment: Just char* constants `#define CLR_R "\x1b[1;31m"` `#define CLR_N "\x1b[0m"`

Comment: @SouravGhosh Why does it matter? I'm guessing they're escape sequences for switching to red and back to no color.

Comment: @Barmar ummm... maybe because it's better to have [mcve]?

Comment: 1) Read [ask] and provide a [mcve]. 2) Don't use a macro where a function will do as well.

Comment: Don't suppress warnings unless you know what is causing it and OK with that.

Comment: @Barmar: So they are obsolete for the question. Why show them?

Comment: ^ ok, I will edit and provide better example

Comment: @EugeneSh. In this case, his code specifically checks for `NULL` and protects against it.

Comment: As @Olaf said, this can be implemented as a function. If you do it like that you won't get a warning.

Comment: @Barmar. I understand. The warning is caused by `printf("%s: %s\n",NULL,"error")`

Comment: ^ yes, but why is it not checked in `(caller==NULL)`

Comment: Do you get the warning if you optimize? The optimizer should be able to tell that the second call will never occur when `caller == NULL`.

Comment: @pfoof But the compiler is seeing a `printf` with hardcoded NULL as the parameter. And it doesn't like it. You can safely suppress it in this case, but better redesign. You can have two macros for example, if you insist on macros.

Comment: Just a suggestion: `void main()` --> `int main(void)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works (gcc, clang):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
#define CLR_R "\x1b[1;31m" 
#define CLR_N "\x1b[0m"

#define printerr(caller,msg)  \
    (caller==NULL)? printf(CLR_R "%s" CLR_N "\n",msg) : \
    printf(CLR_R "%s:" CLR_N " %s\n", ((caller)?(caller):""),msg)


    printerr(NULL,"msg");
    printerr("caller","msg");
}
```

I'm using `((caller)?(caller):"")`to suppress the warning. It will never evaluate to `""`.

You could also use an inline function to the same effect:

```
#define CLR_R "\x1b[1;31m" 
#define CLR_N "\x1b[0m"
static inline int inl_printerr(char const *caller, char const *msg)
{
    if (caller)
        return printf(CLR_R "%s:" CLR_N " %s\n", caller,msg);
    else
        return printf(CLR_R "%s" CLR_N "\n",msg);
}
```

(Recommended as it avoids the typesafety and double-evaluation issues that macros have).

Comment: I'm curious as to why it's been also marked "not useful", given that it is demonstrably useful to the OP. :(

Comment: Because the DV button is rather used for "I don't like it for a generic reason or having a bad mood".